# Ansbile way of having multiple MAILTO environment varialbes in crontab

Tags: cron, ansible, ansible-2.x, mailto

I have to create crontab in Ansible in such a way that the rendered crontab should have multiple `MAILTO` which is based on following cron task. For instance, the final crontab may look like below

```
MAILTO=person1@domain.com
#Ansible: TEST 1
0 * * * * ls -ahl > /dev/null

MAILTO=person2@domain.com
#Ansible: TEST 2
1 * * * * ls -ahl > /dev/null
```

`MAILTO` being an environment variable , it gets overridden if I specify it multiple times
sample of playbook using `env`.

```
- cron:
    env: true
    name: MAILTO
    job: person1@domain.com
    state: "present"
    insertbefore: "TEST 1"
- cron:
    name: "TEST 1"
    job: "ls -ahl > /dev/null"
    state: "present"
    minute: "0"
    hours: "5,2"
- cron:
    env: true
    name: MAILTO
    job: person2@domain.com
    state: "present"
    insertbefore: "TEST 2"
- cron:
    name: "TEST 2"
    job: "ls -ahl > /dev/null"
    state: "present"
    minute: "1"
    hours: "4,2"
```

but no luck and I have also tried using `cronvar`

```
- cronvar:
    name: MAILTO
    value: person1@domain.com
    state: "present"
    insertbefore: "TEST 1"
- cron:
    name: "TEST 1"
    job: "ls -ahl > /dev/null"
    state: "present"
    minute: "0"
    hours: "5,2"
- cronvar:
    name: MAILTO
    value: person2@domain.com
    state: "present"
    insertbefore: "TEST 2"
- cron:
    name: "TEST 2"
    job: "ls -ahl > /dev/null"
    state: "present"
    minute: "1"
    hours: "4,2"
```

again no luck

Could someone point out a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `cronvar` is meant to add variable to the files, which are uniques and since I am not totally sure from [that comment](https://serverfault.com/questions/33504/override-mailto-for-a-single-crontab-entry#comment463502_33511) that having multiple `MAILTO` is something possible on all the implementation of `crontab`, so it is likely that it is not going to be supported by Ansible, I guess your best bet is to resort to a plain old [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/lineinfile_module.html).

The not-so-nice part of this, of course, is that you have to make an host, play or task variable holding the path to the crontab file.
I looked through the documentation quickly, but it seems like there is no fact giving the actual crontab of a user, and since it seems it is part of [the cron module code itself](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/3e9943bc5e7a9cd393757aa8100d7fed80bd316e/lib/ansible/modules/cron.py#L524), I am not sure there will be a nice way to find it out from Ansible itself.

The part identifying where the line should be added, on the other hand seems future proof, as it is clearly documented as an expected behaviour:

> When crontab jobs are managed: the module includes one line with the description of the crontab entry `"#Ansible: <name>"` corresponding to the “name” passed to the module, which is used by future ansible/module calls to find/check the state. The “name” parameter should be unique, and changing the “name” value will result in a new cron task being created (or a different one being removed).

<sup>*From documentation: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/cron_module.html*</sup>

With all this, given the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    cron_file: /etc/crontabs/root
  
  tasks:
    - cron:
        name: "TEST 1"
        job: "ls -ahl > /dev/null"
        state: "present"
        minute: "0"
        hour: "5,2"
      register: cron

    - lineinfile:
        path: "{{ cron_file }}"
        insertbefore: '#Ansible: TEST 1'
        line: 'MAILTO=person1@domain.com'

    - cron:
        name: "TEST 2"
        job: "ls -ahl > /dev/null"
        state: "present"
        minute: "1"
        hour: "4,2"
    
    - lineinfile:
        path: "{{ cron_file }}"
        insertbefore: '#Ansible: TEST 2'
        line: 'MAILTO=person2@domain.com'
```

This yields the recap:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [cron] ********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [cron] ********************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

And in the */etc/crontabs/root* of the Alpine used to test:

```
MAILTO=person1@domain.com
#Ansible: TEST 1
0 5,2 * * * ls -ahl > /dev/null
MAILTO=person2@domain.com
#Ansible: TEST 2
1 4,2 * * * ls -ahl > /dev/null
```

Last but not least, rerunning the exact same playbook show the idempotency is respected:

```
PLAY [all] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [cron] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [cron] ********************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [lineinfile] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=4    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: thanks, it works but how can I add duplicate `MAILTO=person1@domain.com` lines, `lineinfile` only adds single unique line.

Comment: to have duplicate `MAILTO=person1@domain.com` use `regex: '#Ansible: TEST 1'`, basically `regex` is same as `insertbefore`.
task may look like this


`- lineinfile:`
        `path: "{{ cron_file }}"`
        `insertbefore: '#Ansible: TEST 1'`
        `regex: '#Ansible: TEST 1'`
        `firstmatch: true`
        `line: 'MAILTO=person1@domain.com'`

Comment: not a correct solution, anyone knows how to  add duplicate `MAILTO=person1@domain.com` lines before ansible task

Comment: ok there is a nasty hack use a `regex` which does not match anything that would do the trick